# Generate Subreport on each Report page

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Good people!
I am trying to add a subreport to the main report and it must be repeated on each page. I already try to put the "RepeatWith", but it is not allowed to subreport.
Also try to add it as header to the "tablix", with the "RepeatOnNewPage", but it repeats it without regenerating the information (DataSet) of the subreport itself, leaving literally the same.(Because I take it as "Static")

Any other idea?

Comment: I detail a little more: The subreport is the Header, which I had to encapsulate so as not to repeat it in each of the reports, what I am trying to obtain is the Page Number for each new page that is assigned.

Comment: Headers don't repeat calculated stuff like sub-reports. Have you considered using a formula for calculating page numbers?  They can be tricky to get right, but usually are the best/preferred approach.

Comment: Good tgolisch! What do you mean with formulas to calculate page numbers? use report code?

Comment: I discarded the option to calculate it by the number of records that occupies a page, because this option will have to do the calculation for each report that makes

Comment: There is a way to set up a running-variable, to collect the page numbers as they are being displayed. Like a function, it gives the number each time, and adds 1 to the current number.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Have you also looked at the difference in "Formula", Built-in-fields, `PageNumber` vs `OverallPageNumber`?  Maybe tried both/either.

Comment: If those two don't give you what you need, you can define a variable in Report->Report Properties->Variables. Also, you could create a function that increments the variable (each time it is called) and returns the new value under Report Properties->Code.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017